# Slack application does not send links to my bot

Tags: botframework, slack

I added Slaсk channel:

[image]

But when a user sends a message with a link to my SLACK application, the link does not come.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you mean.   Can you give a more detailed example.  Are you saying that when plain text is sent that your bot receives it, but that when a link is sent your bot doesn't?  Have you set a breakpoint in your bot to confirm this?  How about other channels?  Does it work in the emulator?

Comment: I created Slack app (@iprill), and then add this application to my team (iprill-team.slack.com) - http://prntscr.com/ds56p8. I can add you to my Slack team for the test.

My Slack app (@iprill) is integrated with Microsoft botframework - http://prntscr.com/ds55dh. And Microsoft botframework integrated with my CRM system Bitrix24.

I get messages from Slack in Bitrix24.

But when I write a message to @ iprill with a link - http://prntscr.com/ds58vf, the link does not come in Bitrix24 - http://prntscr.com/ds59ai.

http://prntscr.com/ds59h6 - Graphic integration scheme.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed screen shots.  I tried adding iPrill to a slack channel and it isn't responding.  Can you send me the full JSON that your bot receives from the Bot Framework?

Comment: I got your message on my Bitrix24 - http://prntscr.com/dsjhai. This is your message?

Comment: Yes.  Just sent another.   Can you send me the full JSON dump of what your bot is receiving?

Comment: JSON for Microsoft bot or Slack app?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/dsweae - Your message

Comment: Can you send me the JSON that is being sent to your bot.  (Hard to debug w/o that.)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/dthymg - where to find the JSON ?

Comment: Hmm..  That link shows me the SlackAPI setup page.  What's the JSON sent to the API controller in your bot?

Comment: Where to see it? :(

I have created an Slack application for the Microsoft instructions - http://prntscr.com/dtox22
http://prntscr.com/dtoxrw
http://prntscr.com/dtoxum
http://prntscr.com/dtoy57

Comment: You must have written some code that is receiving the messages from the post (e.g. the messages controller in C#).   What is being sent to the Post method?

Comment: I did not write the code. I created the application as it says here - http://prntscr.com/dtyoxu > http://prntscr.com/dtynub

Comment: That's not creating an application that's simply enabling the connection to your bot.  You still need an endpoint to handle the incoming post requests to your bot.  What is https://im.bitrix.info/imwebhook/?eh=fxxx?

Comment: https://www.bitrix24.com/ - my CRM.
http://prntscr.com/du4sr0 - This configuration integration with Microsoft botframevork

Comment: Interesting.  This is the first we've heard of Bitrix.  Looks like they have a BotFramework connector.  Can you provide a link to their set up page?  I was trying to find it on my own, but I don't know Russian.

Comment: Can you give me your email? I invite you to test Bitrix24.

Comment: Hello! How are you? Where are you?)